# Bind Dropdownlist in FormView

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, formview

I want to fill dropdownlist which is inside FormView. I'm writing this code at PageLoad event:

```
DropDownList ddlTypeOfPayment = dvBooking.FindControl("ddlTypeOfPayment") as DropDownList;
```

But when I compile itraises the error "Object reference is not set to an instance of object". 
I'm using objectdatasource to bind formview.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't put it in PageLoad you put it in the `protected void FormView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)` event of your formview.

You'll want to do this instead too:

```
dvBooking.Row.FindControl("ddlTypeOfPayment");
```

Comment: Available events of FormView are DataBound and ItemCreated. I've checked on both but same problem